# Android - Good way to pass bitmap to an activity fastly

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bitmap

What is the best way to send a bitmap to an another activity **without store on device** ?
If I putExtra(Bitmap), i have buffer problems because Bitmap are too big.
And now I use this but it's too slow :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ImageScreen.class);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
    intent.putExtra("image",bytes);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the bitmap is too big, in that case the best solution is to write the `Bitmap` in the private storage of your app, and then send the file path to the next activity. The code to write the bitmap to a file and retrieve the file path will be as follows

```
public String createBitmapFile(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String fileName = "image";
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
        FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fileName = null;
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

Then in the next activity you can do something like

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context
                    .openFileInput(fileName));
```

To delete the file later on, you can simply use.

```
if(activity.deleteFile(imageName))
    Log.i(TAG, "Image deleted");
```

Comment: How can i remove the file after what i want to do?